# Съезжает блок количества показов вопроса

Tags: дефект, дизайн

- Mozilla Iceweasel 38.7.1
- Mozilla Firefox 45.3.0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошёл год и два месяца, есть ли шансы на исправление этого сдвига? (На основной [мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297548/shifting-of-the-blocks-of-question-views-on-ru-stackoverflow-com))

Comment: Наблюдаю подобный эффект в FF 49.0.1 при уменьшении масштаба до 50%. На 100% всё нормально.

Comment: Кстати, я думаю, если есть возможность, то подобные (общие для всех сайтов сети Stack Exchange) вопросы лучше публиковать на SE.Meta. Больше шансов получить фидбек быстрее.

Comment: @alexolut на других сайтах с такой проблемой не сталкивался.

Comment: Все 160+ проверили? :)

Comment: @alexolut ограничился двумя enSO и ruSO.

Comment: Сейчас вот проверил на 50% масштаба ruSO сбоит, а enSO нет. Всё-таки кодовая база по части форматирования разная получается.

Comment: @alexolut, вероятно, у нас текст длиннее.

Comment: Проблема ещё имеет место быть?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ нет..

Answer (score 10):

Верстальщики нашпиговали выровненный по центру текст `padding`-ами, а у двух блоков из трёх (у "голосов" и "ответов", но не у "показов") прозевали `max-width`. У всех трёх есть только `min-width`. Достаточно немного увеличить текст надписей, чтобы словить косяк, а увеличение может происходить по тысяче причин (в данном случае шрифт какой-то подозрительный).

Так что, даже если баг наблюдают не все, он всё-таки есть. Верстальщикам нужно учиться, что не у всех одни и те же язык, ось и шрифты.

Answer (score 1):

Если проблема наблюдается исключительно на отличных от 100% масштабах, то [с точки зрения SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287546/tab-underline-issue-for-russian-stack-overflow#comment933066_287546) это не является дефектом:

> We don't support "different scale factors", only 100%.

А стало быть и не подлежит исправлению.

Comment: Это при 100% проблема, поэтому приходится работать на масштабе чуть большем чем сто.

Comment: @edem как я уже писал ранее в комментариях, у меня не получается повторить такое поведение на 100%. И я по-прежнему рекомендую написать баг репорт на MSE. Для увеличения он-топичности хорошо бы найти подтверждение такого поведения например на других локализованных сайтах SO: pt, es, jp. Ну и привести больше информации по воспроизведению, версию ОС добавить, ссылки на страницы, выделить проблемные места цветом на картинках и т.п.