# Странное выравнивание элементов в списке всех вопросов

Tags: дефект, вопросы, дизайн

У каждого участника этого форума есть подобие собственной комнаты, где он может увидеть свои награды, свои вопросы/ответы, свою репутацию и тд. И вот там есть несколько прямоугольных частей, например: вопросы, ответы, репутация, метки. Эти прямоугольники находятся на вкладке сводка. Вот если я перехожу в [прямоугольник вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions), то я замечаю что выравнивание элементов списка, а именно вопросов, по левому краю, довольно нестандартное. Часть элементов выравнивается нормально, а потом один может выбиться из группы и выглядит в итоге не очень красиво. Может уже кто-то писал про эту проблему, я честно говоря не следил) Если есть подобный вопрос, то я свой могу отметить дубликатом, это не есть проблема. В любом случае я надеюсь что хоть чем-то помог. Вот например список моих вопросов на мете:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Одна картинка заменяет тысячу слов. А еще можно ссылок добавить.

Comment: @alexolut, добавил картинку, если не очень будет видно, то постараюсь найти у себя еще более выражено)

Comment: На главной такая же фигня.

Comment: на главной странице там где все вопросы?

Comment: я просто не могу понять если честно, это глюк у меня или у сайта

Comment: Не очень представляю как это может быть Вашим глюком :)

Comment: ну может у меня браузер проблемный) со зрением у меня все вроде норм, хотя давно проверялся :D

Comment: Более наглядную картинку можете взять здесь: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47042660#47042660

Comment: ну тогда я не сказал ничего нового в своем вопросе)))

Comment: Да не, вопрос нужен, мне просто день было оформлять. [meta-tag:ад-перфекциониста]

Comment: рад был помочь)

Comment: workaround: `.question-counts > * { width: 4.5em; }`

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2811 схожий вопрос.